# How to cancel async image loading for uitableviewcells on new search

Tags: ios, swift

I start a search on my server for profiles of users. As the user types usernames, different suggested profiles appear in a cell in a `UITableView`. Each profile has an image associated with it. The image is loaded asynchronously once the user types, via the `cellForItem(at:)` function. When the user types to search it cancels my search request to the server, however it also needs to cancel the asynchronous requests. There may be more than one request happening at a time - how should I keep track of them?

My code to download an image is like this:

```
model.downloadImage(
    withURL: urlString,
    completion: { [weak self] error, image in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        if error == nil, let theImage = image {
            // Store the image in to our cache
            strongSelf.model.imageCache[urlString] = theImage
            // Update the cell with our image
            if let cell = strongSelf.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableCell {
                cell.profileImage.image = theImage
            }
        } else {
             print("Error downloading image: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
)
```

Note that I can add `request = model.downloadImage(...` if I wanted to, but `request` would only hold a pointer to the last time that the `downloadImage()` function was called.

Answer (score 0):

For such purpose I recommend using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki). It's powerful 3rd party library for downloading and caching images. With kingfisher you can achieve what you want by simply calling:

```
// In table view delegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //...
    cell.imageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCD, with iOS 8 & macOS 10.10 DispatchWorkItem was introduced, which provide this exact functionality (a task it can be canceled) in a very easy to use API.

This is an example:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    // We keep track of the pending work item as a property
    private var pendingRequestWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // Cancel the currently pending item
        pendingRequestWorkItem?.cancel()
        // Wrap our request in a work item
        let requestWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            self?.model.downloadImage(...
        }
        // Save the new work item and execute it after 250 ms
        pendingRequestWorkItem = requestWorkItem
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(250),
                                      execute: requestWorkItem)
    }
}
```

In your case, you need to know through the delegate (example: TextField) when the user enters information.